# Pylance is enabled, but not working, the settings.json file mentions pylance

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

Pylance is enabled, but not working, the settings.json file mentions pylance

.vscode/settings.json:

```
{
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try to describe your problem with some details.

Comment: i dont really know how to describe better, thats like everything i can show, that it is enabled, it is set in settings.json, but does not work at all

Comment: Possibly related: [Pylance not working in VSCode Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65561436/5353461)

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd images aren't displaying... see if you can format them like your first.

Comment: @TomHale not really related, his pylance is showing a sign of life, mines not alive at all, the images show that it is enabled in the vs code store, and that it does not do anything, not even saying its unknown or unidentified

Answer (score 4):

Pylance requires a latest version of VS Code.

If you open the integrated terminal, go to the Output tab and select Python Language Server from the dropdown, you might see an error message similar to "The language client requires VS Code version ^1.51.0 but received version 1.50.1" If so, updating VS Code to the latest version might resolve the issue.

Comment: This fixed an issue for me, where pylance was running inside a devcontainer that was newer than my local VSCode version. Thanks!